# How to move DIV pixel by pixel

Tags: javascript, css

I have a  DIV setup like this.

```
  <div id="parent" class="parent">
            <div id="child" class="child">
            </div>
   </div>
```

Styles

```
    <style>
    .parent{
    float:left; height:300; width:300px; background-color:#00ff00;
    }
    .child{
    float:left; height:60; width:60px; background-color:#00ff00;
    }
    </style>


<script>
            function move(){
                while(m < 100){
                document.getElementByid('child').style.marginTop = m;
                m = m+1;
                }
            }
            move();
 </script>
```

I want to move inner DIV ( named child)  pixel by pixel from top to bottom by 100 pixels.
I think it can be done using style.marginTop = '' and settimeout() function

But still not able to get this working.

Comment: Show us your JavaScript code.

Comment: do you mean animating?

Comment: @dogoku yes animating.

Comment: I would recommend doing this using Jquery's animate function, it does most of the heavy lifting for you. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: If you want some animation you can try jquery.

Comment: You could also use CSS transitions if browser support isn't a concern.

Comment: was wondering if someone would mention transitions or animate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you can animate your div with vanilla JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/z6F7m/1/

**JavaScript**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('animated'),
    top = parseInt(elem.style.marginTop, 10) || 0,
    step = 1;

function animate() {
    if (top < 100) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        elem.style.marginTop = top + 'px';
        top += step;
    }
}

animate();
```

I highly recommend you to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`, if the browser does not supports `requestAnimationFrame` you can fallback to `setTimeout`.

Comment: The Paul Irish shim might be worth including too: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var element = document.getElementById('child');
for (var i=0; i != 100; i++){
    element.style.marginTop += 1;
}
```

That'll loop 100 times and add 1 to the marginTop each loop.

I'd suggest using jQuery thought, because with jQuery you can simply do

```
$("#child").animate({ marginTop: 100 });
```

**EDIT**

Top example doesn't make sense, try this.

```
var element = document.getElementById('animated');
    for (var i = 0; i != 100; i++) {
    currentTop = parseInt(element.style.marginTop) || 0;
    newTop = parseInt(currentTop + 1);
    element.style.marginTop = newTop + "px";
}
```

This is also stupid because it loops way to fast and by the time the browser renders the box, it's already 100px from the top. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/k53Jm/)

Again, go with the [jQuery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/k53Jm/1/).

Comment: What if `marginTop` is `'10px'`, won't this make it `10px11111...`, and will we even have an animation?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is using jQuery's [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function, which would require merely writing:

```
$(element).animate({ 'top': '100px' });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GFWW6/)

Comment: Top will only work if it's position absolute. margin-top is the best for this situation.

Comment: It will also work for position: relative - as you most probably realize. Not knowing the real-life example of usage, there's no point in arguing which method suits best.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following fiddle. I did it without jquery.

```
 var step = 0;
 window.setInterval(function(){
    var value = (++step)*100;
    if (value<300)
        document.getElementById("child").style.marginTop=value+"px";
    else
       step = -1;
 },1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pasindur/EbHt5/